# How to open multiple projects into the CAST IRON integration tool?

Tags: casting, project, iron

I am learning the cast iron tool [(http://www.castiron.com/)](http://www.castiron.com/) which is widely used now a days for integration purpose,but i can only open 1 project and if i want to open the other project at the same time than I have to close the 1st project and open the 2nd project.

So many times i need to have to open the 2 projects at the same time but i dont know in which way i can open the projects?

can any body give me any urgent solution for the same to open the multiple projects at the same time and to switch between them?

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of the studio that is a minor version different than the version you are working with. This will let you open two projects side by side and copy and paste between them. I do this so much that I won't even do an upgrade until the second release is available to open my template projects.

Answer (score 0):

'tponthieuz' answer is one option. Another option is to install the studio in a test vm and load your other project for reference. If you have more than one monitor, this really works well.

Answer (score 0):

copy the "Cast Iron Studio" folder from where it is installed(for e.g c:) and paste it in other drive(e:\ or d:) and open the studio from it,open your project in this studio.
it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Install the castiron studio in another directory. Now you will be having two exe of castiron studio in two different dir. From both of them you can launch CastIron now.